# finding timestamp difference for a day in R

Tags: r

I have data in the interval of 15 minutes and i need to find the time difference between the next record and current record using R but i am not able to do. Can some help here?

```
    TIMESTAMP         ID  timediff
07/29/2014 10:15 AM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 10:45 AM 189252  0:30
07/29/2014 11:00 AM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 11:15 AM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 11:30 AM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 11:45 AM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 12:00 PM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 12:15 PM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 12:30 PM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 01:00 PM 189252  0:30
07/29/2014 01:15 PM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 01:30 PM 189252  0:15
07/29/2014 01:45 PM 189252  0:15
```

Comment: Hint: you can use something like `> strptime('07/29/2014 10:15 AM', format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")-strptime('07/29/2014 10:00 AM', format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
Time difference of 15 mins
> `

Comment: since this is an continuos data i dont want to do hard code..i want to use loop and then work but i am not able to.If you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward as long as your data are in an appropriate date-time format:

```
> foo <- as.POSIXct(c("07/29/2014 10:15","07/29/2014 10:45"),
  format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
> foo
[1] "2014-07-29 10:15:00 CEST" "2014-07-29 10:45:00 CEST"
> diff(foo)
Time difference of 30 mins
```

Look at `?as.POSIXct` and `?strptime`.

Comment: i know strptime and posixct but the thing is this i dont like hard coding.
say when you have n timestamp for n id's then?

Comment: `diff` will work on vectors: `diff(as.POSIXct(rep("07/29/2014 10:15",10),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))`

Comment: thanks  Stephan Kolassa this works....if you can help when we have n no. of ID's with different starting timestamps how to find timediff for each ID

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what result you want if you have multiple IDs. A good place to start may be the `by()` function, with your IDs fed into the `INDICES` parameter.

Comment: can you give the syntax? maybe that can work. i am not sure whether my approach to the problem is correct or not but i am keen to do mistakes

Comment: @Stephen Kolassa stackoverflow is not allowing me upload images or else i would have told you more

Comment: you check the link http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-Statement-In-R-td4699745.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff` if the `TIMESTAMP` entries are `Date` objects - use `as.Date()` to makes sure.

```
now1<-Sys.time()
now2<-Sys.time()
now3<-Sys.time()
now4<-Sys.time()

df<-data.frame(TIMESTAMP=c(now1,now2,now3,now4))
df$differences<-c(NA,diff(df$TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: thanks this works!! but say if we have n no.of ID's with different starting timestamps